# winforms designer behavior issue (tabs changed automatically, when trying put control on it)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, layout

VS 2010
I have simple win forms without code, just tab with 3 pages and buttons on each tabpage.

When i trying to put button  on tabpage (on the left side of page it works fine, if i trying to put btn on right side of the page ...the  designer will automatically change tabpage to another

Maybe problems is in this code

```
  this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
   this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
 this.groupBox8.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.groupBox8.PerformLayout();
   ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).EndInit();
```

P.S. When i delete all controls from one my tab(which always selected automatically) and designer work fine
Later i delete rectangle controls(they are from Visual basic power pack and now designer works fine)

Comment: name your controls...and from where did you get these codes? did you write them??

Comment: yes it is autoamically named like tabpage 1,tabpage2 and control names also have button1,button2 etc

Comment: and there are a lot of controls 15-30 on each tab page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved wheni deleted Visual Basic power pack rectangle controls from my page tab. This control have bug in vs 2010